# How to save 2 item as 1 image in camera roll?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

Qs 2 : I was playing around with the cameraroll.

```
var bitmapData:BitmapData = new BitmapData();
bitmapData.draw(firstitem);

if (CameraRoll.supportsAddBitmapData)  
{
    var cameraroll:CameraRoll = new CameraRoll();
    cameraroll.addBitmapData(bitmapData);
}


<s:Image id="firstitem"/>
```

Imagine I have another

```
<s:Image id="seconditem"/>
```

How to store 2 together as 1 image?

I tried

bitmapData.draw(firstitem,seconditem)

bitmapData.draw(firstitem),(seconditem);

but there was an error.

Answer (score 0):

What you can try to do is, 
create a bitmap data that will contain the 2 images,

```
var bitmapData:BitmapData = new BitmapData();
```

and then use [copypixel,](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/BitmapData.html#copyPixels%28%29)

```
bitmapData.copyPixels(bmd1, rect, new Point(0, 0));
bitmapData.copyPixels(bmd2, rect, new Point(bmd1.width, 0));
```

of course, the parameters of the function are :

- bmd:BitmapData the one to copy
- rect:Rectangle the rectangle to take from bmd ( should be (x,y,width,height) of the original images)
- (x,y):Point : which is the destination point on bitmapData

Cheers !!

---

your example

- image 1 : 500x500
- image 2 : 250x250

  image_1.copyPixels(image_2,new Rectangle(0,0,250,250), new Point(125,125));

and this means we are going to copy image_2 inside image_1, (0,0,250,250) means positon (0,0) from image_2 with the width and height 250,250, and (125,125) is the position where to add image_2 inside image_1

Comment: Hi Khalil,
Thanks for your reply, 
I still not quite understand how to apply copyPixels
For example my firstitem is an image size 500x500, seconditem is another image size 250x250 in the middle of first item,
what i am trying to achieve here is store both thing as 1 image

Comment: @LydiaPiglet you mean, you want to add seconditem inside first item, sry but didn't get what you asked here

Comment: hi khalil, thanks for your reply again. yes ,that what i meant, like for example i got a small square and 1 big square ,position the small square somewhere within the big square, and What i ask was how to store both as 1 image in camera roll

using bitmapData.draw ,how to draw 2 item and from there
    cameraroll.addBitmapData(bitmapData);
---------
For the example you gave, 
image_1.copyPixels(image_2,(0,0,250,250), (125,125));
after which how do i relate to bitmapData and from there i can use     cameraroll.addBitmapData(bitmapData);?

once again thank you so much

Comment: ofc image_1 and image_2 are BitmapData, and you add image_1 in the cameraroll

Comment: hi khalil,still couldnt get it right, it seem quite complicated

feel like giving up, but i am determine to learn something new.


Description Resource Path Location Type
1067: Implicit coercion of a value of type int to an unrelated type flash.geom:Point. test.mxml /test/src/views line 109 Flex Problem

Description Resource Path Location Type
1067: Implicit coercion of a value of type int to an unrelated type flash.geom:Rectangle. test.mxml /test/src/views line 109 Flex Problem


rect.copyPixels(rect2,(0,0,292,292),(13,0));

Comment: try to declare a point var `myPoint:Point = new Point(13,0);` and change `rect.copyPixels(rect2,(0,0,292,292),myPoint);`

Comment: hi , left this error

Description Resource Path Location Type
1067: Implicit coercion of a value of type int to an unrelated type flash.geom:Rectangle. test.mxml /test/src/views line 109 Flex Problem

Comment: my bad ! `rect.copyPixels(rect2,new Rectangle(0,0,292,292),myPoint);`

Comment: thank you so much, there no error ,but when i click, the whole interface when haywire,it appear on the screen, there is not suppose to be any output as it's suppose to store in camera roll
guess my foundation is not there.

is there another easy way? 
I am able to store 1 item at first, now i have a seconditem, is there no other way than using copypixels?

var bitmapData:BitmapData = new BitmapData();
bitmapData.draw(firstitem);

if (CameraRoll.supportsAddBitmapData)  
{
    var cameraroll:CameraRoll = new CameraRoll();
    cameraroll.addBitmapData(bitmapData);
}